# sdkmanager license

Tags: android-studio

I try to create react-native project and i installed android studio in D:/ instead of C:/
and when i try to accept android license

```
D:\APPS\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat --licenses
```

it didn't work

```
Error: Could not find or load main class '-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=D:\APPS\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\\..
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: '-Dcom/android/sdklib/toolsdir=D:\APPS\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\\//
```

I tried to install other veriosns but also the same result

try to install other versions and try to re install android studio nothing work